# Enumerable set of trigonometric function

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the  set  $S = \{x \in \Bbb{R} | \sin (\frac{1}{x}) = 0 \}$ 
Is the set $S$ enumerable?

I think it's enumerable but cannot construct the bijective function between $S$ and $\Bbb{N}$

Comment: Does the edit make your question the same? in order to write mathematical symbols, use LaTeX!

Comment: Yes of course it is the same

Comment: @SMukherjee it's probably advisable to exclude zero from the universal set, since we can't even make sense of $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at $x\in[0,2\pi]$:
 $\sin(x)=0\iff x=\pi$ or $x=0$.
Since the function $\sin$ is periodic and its period is $2\pi$, we know that
$\sin(\pi+k 2\pi) = \sin(0+k2\pi)=0$ for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Finally, we can write your set as

$$S=\{k 2\pi\,\colon k\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{{\pi}+k2\pi\}=\{k\pi\,\colon k\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$

Comment: Here it is 1/k*pi but what is the function then

Comment: Ah, sorry.. But it is really easy to adapt the former to your case.. Just like Guido A. did above

Answer (score 0):

Note that since $\sin(t) = 0$ if and only if $t \in 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$,

$$
S = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} : \sin(\frac{1}{x}) = 0\} = \{\frac{1}{t} \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} : \sin(t) = 0 \} = \{\frac{1}{2k\pi}\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}}
$$

Thus, your set $S$ is indexed by $\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ which is countably infinite. If you want an explicit bijection, you can first define a bijective function $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ and then take $g: n \in \mathbb{N} \mapsto \frac{1}{2\pi f(n)} \in S$.

Concretely, you can take

$$
f(n) = \cases{-k \text{ if } n = 2k-1 \\ \quad k \text{ if } n = 2k}
$$